# vscode cannot reconnect to existing jupyter notebook server when waking my laptop

Tags: python, jupyter, vscode

I recently switched from browser to vs code for using jupyter notebook and the IDE-like features (e.g. auto-complete, debugging, etc) provided by VS code is really so much better than a browser. But one thing bothers me is that **whenever I wake my laptop from sleep mode**, it often has issue re-connecting to existing jupyter notebook server (in my case localhost:8888). When using browser, I simply refresh the page and it works. But VS code does not seem to be able to "reconnect" to the server. I also tried close/reopen my ipynb notebook, but still no luck. I could just restart the server, but I would lose all my saved results so it is usually not the best option.

Comment: There are fixed bugs in VSCode related to your problem description (e.g. [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8159)), but their patches were released on early 2022. Could it be that your VSCode is not up to date?

Comment: Also, this question was apparently cross-posted on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/17twmff/cannot_reconnect_to_existing_jupyter_notebook/)

Comment: @noe no my vscode is already up-to-date, this issue still exists